# unable to fetch json data from ip url

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am unable to fetch cross domain json data here is my code below which doesn't work

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="images"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var furl= "http://192.168.2.36/gemadmin/display.php?callback=?";
  $.getJSON( furl)
    .done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this code works properly since its just localhost

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="images"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var furl= "http://localhost/gemadmin/display.php";
  $.getJSON( furl)
    .done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

why is the first version not working ? and what is the solution to make it work?

server code(display.php)

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    $sql = "select * from menu;";
    $result= $mysqli->query($sql);
    $data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $data );
    ?>
```

**The answer:**
Found the answer instead of $.getJSON() use $.get and do a json parse 
example
    
    
    
      
      jQuery.getJSON demo
      
      img {
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
      }

```
<div id="images"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var furl= "http://localhost/gemadmin/display.php?callback=?";
  $.get( furl)
    .done(function( data ) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj);
    });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

don't forget to add '**callback=?**'to your url

Comment: simply because your accessing `admin` data, that request is invalid unless you are logged-in in the other site.

Comment: You have found the cause already: "_i am unable to fetch cross domain json data_". Cross domain Ajax requests are not permitted unless you set the appropriate CORS headers. There are plenty discussions for this already if you search for the terms "ajax" and "cors".

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This

```
            $.ajax({
                    url: "URL",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify("YOUR JSON"),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },

                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert('Failed');
                        alert(x.responseText);
                        alert(x.status);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("demo_ajax_json.js",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

demo_ajax_json.js

```
{ 
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 25
}
```

A simple example